# Is !list.isEmpty() and list.size()>0 equal?

Tags: java

I've seen code as below:

```
     if (!substanceList.isEmpty() && (substanceList.size() > 0))
    {
      substanceText = createAmountText(substanceList);
    }
```

Would the following be a valid refactor?

```
     if (!substanceList.isEmpty())
    {
      substanceText = createAmountText(substanceList);
    }
```

I would be grateful for an explanation of the above code and whether the second version may cause errors?

Comment: You could make the method createAmoutText deal with checking if the size is > 0.

Comment: what is better ocde, isEmpty or .size() ?

Comment: @PmanAce That would change the meaning of the code, since you can't back out of assignment.

Comment: `!isEmpty()` exactly means `size()>0`, then one is redundant

Comment: I’d always use isEmpty in case you have a weird  container where the size function is O(N).

Comment: They do exactly the same, but if your `substanceList` has not been initialized you might get a NullPointer Exception. 
With `substanceList != null && !substanceList.isEmpty())` you are on the safe side.

Comment: @djnose is then better to check is it null or not as same condition  ?

Comment: @djnose you'd get an NPE with both.

Comment: @djnose checking for null first isn't refactoring, it changes the semantics.

Comment: @uma As @Bathsheba said, `!isEmpty()` is probably always better, incase the `size` function of some given container counts its elements.

Comment: true @AndyTurner, yes uma. Except you know it can never be null.

Comment: @George however, note that [`AbstractCollection.isEmpty()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.isEmpty%28%29) is implemented by checking `size() == 0`. In other words, you likely won't get any worse performance by using `isEmpty()`, but a collection may be able to provide a better implementation.

Comment: @djnose "Except you know it can never be null" don't just throw in random null checks. If you expect it not to be null, treat it like it's not null, and get the NPE right here where it's important; then fix the reason why it is null. If you don't expect it to be null, checking for null just kicks the can down the road to the next place where it needs not to be null. *Only check if it is null* if you know it could be null.

Comment: @AndyTurner not the dumbest thing the java bods came up with; but close.

Comment: @Bathsheba which dumbest thing are you referring to? :) null? (Personally, I think autoboxing is the dumbest thing, with autoboxing rules in conditional expressions coming a close second)

Comment: @AndyTurner, yeah, i agree. since uma asked for potential errors i just wanted to point out that this could be one of them. How you treat them etc. is a complete different story. imho

Comment: @AndyTurner: yes the autoboxing mess especially w.r.t. the ternary conditional are top of my list. My objection to the default implementation of isEmpty means that any reasonable programmer has to override that implementation and a compiler is unlikely to earn you of that.

Comment: @Bathsheba given how frequently I have had to implement a collection, that's in the lower leagues of things that irritate me about Java ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If in doubt, read the Javadoc:

[`Collection.isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#isEmpty--):

> Returns true if this collection contains no elements.

[`Collection.size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#size--):

> Returns the number of elements in this collection

So, assuming the collection is implemented correctly:

```
collection.isEmpty() <=> collection.size() == 0
```

Or, conversely:

```
!collection.isEmpty() <=> collection.size() != 0
```

Since the number of elements should only be positive, this means that:

```
!collection.isEmpty() <=> collection.size() > 0
```

So yes, the two forms are equivalent.

**Caveat**: actually, they're only equivalent if your collection isn't being modified from another thread at the same time.

This:

```
!substanceList.isEmpty() && (substanceList.size() > 0)
```

is equivalent to, by the logic I present above:

```
!substanceList.isEmpty() && !substanceList.isEmpty()
```

You can only simplify this to

```
!substanceList.isEmpty()
```

if you can guarantee that its value doesn't change in between evaluations of `substanceList.isEmpty()`.

Practically, it is unlikely that you need to care about the difference between these cases, at least at this point in the code. You *might* need to care about the list being changed in another thread, however, if it can become empty before (or while) executing `createAmountText`. But that's not something that was introduced by this refactoring.

TL;DR: using `if (!substanceList.isEmpty()) {` does practically the same thing, and is clearer to read.

Answer (score 5):

The only difference between the first and the second approach is that the first approach performs a redundant check. nothing else.

Thus, you'd rather avoid the redundant check and go with the second approach.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can read the source code downloaded in the JDK:

```
/**
 * Returns <tt>true</tt> if this list contains no elements.
 *
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if this list contains no elements
 */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}
```

I think that this settles all the queries.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation of `isEmpty()` in `AbstractCollection` is as follows:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size() == 0;
}
```

So you can safely assume that `!list.isEmpty()` is equivalent to `list.size() > 0`.

As for "what is better code", if you want to check if the list is empty or not, `isEmpty()` is definitely more expressive.
Subclasses might also override `isEmpty()` from `AbstractCollection` and implement in more efficient manner than `size() == 0`. So (purely theoretically) `isEmpty()` might be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

The [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) for `Collection.size()` and `Collection.isEmpty()` say:

> `boolean isEmpty()`
>
> Returns true if this collection contains no elements.
>
> `int size()`
>
> Returns the number of elements in this collection

Since "contains no elements" implies that the number of elements in the collection is zero, it follows that `list.isEmpty()` and `list.size() == 0` will evaluate to the same value.

> I want to some explanation of above code

The second version is correct.  The first version looks like it was written either by an automatic code generator, or a programmer who doesn't really understand Java.  There is no *good* reason to write the code that way.

(Note: if some other thread could be concurrently modifying the list, then both versions are problematic unless there is proper synchronization.  If the list operations are not synchronized then may be memory hazards.  But in the first version, there is also the possibility of a race condition ... where the list appears be empty and have a non-zero size!)

> and want to know second way may be caused some error.

It won't.

---

Incidentally `list.isEmpty()` is preferable to `list.size() == 0` for a couple of reasons:

- It is more concise (fewer characters).
- It expresses the *intent* of your code more precisely.
- It may be more efficient.  Some collection implementations may need to *count* the elements in the collection to compute the size.  That may be an `O(N)` operation, and could other undesirable effects.  For example, if a collection is a lazy list that only gets reified as you iterate the elements, then calling `size()` may result in excessive memory use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be refactored as you did. The issue with both approaches is that you would do the check every time you want to call the method `createAmountText` on a List. This means you would be repeating the logic, a better way would be to use DRY (don't Repeat Yourself) principle and factor these checks into your method.
So your method's body should encapsulated by this check.

It should look like:

```
<access modifier> String createAmountText(List substanceList){
   if(substanceList != null && !substanceList.isEmpty()){
       <The methods logic>
   }
   return null;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure - the two methods can be used to express the same thing.

But worth adding here: going for `size() > 0` is somehow a **more** direct violation of the [Tell, don't ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle: you access an "implementation detail", to then make a decision based on that.

In that sense, `isEmpty()` should be your preferred choice here!

Of course, you are **still** violating TDA when using `isEmpty()` - because you are again fetching status from some object to then make a decision on it.

So the really best choice would be to write code that doesn't need at all to make such a query to *internal* state of your collection to then drive decisions on it. Instead, simply make sure that `createAmountText()` properly deals with you passing in an *empty* list! Why should *users* of this list, or of that method need to care whether the list is empty or not?!

Long story short: maybe that is "over thinking" here - but again: not using these methods would lead you to write less code! And that is always an indication of a good idea.